# Error creating database with multiple primary key columns and referencing foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, database

I've been having an issue when creating a database. Each table has a primary key with many foreign keys used also. The issue I have is that I keep getting the error

```
SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view
```

I don't know what is causing this and is flagging the PROJECT_RECORDS table as the issue. I have used the same method in the PROJECT_TABLES table.

SQL/Oracle

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT_DB
(DB_ID number (3) NOT NULL primary key,
DB_NAME varchar2 (25) NOT NULL,
DB_DESCRIPTION varchar2 (75) NOT NULL,
DB_DATE date NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT_DATATYPE
(DATATYPE_NAME varchar2 (20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DATATYPE_DATATYPE varchar2(50) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT_TABLES (
PROJECT_ID number(3) not null references PROJECT_DB(DB_ID) on delete cascade,
PROJECT_FIELDNAME varchar2(25) not null,
PROJECT_DATATYPE varchar2(50) not null references PROJECT_DATATYPE(DATATYPE_NAME),
PROJECT_LENGTH number(3),
PROJECT_REQUIRED varchar2(8),
PROJECT_LISTCOLUMNID number (3) not null,
primary key(PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_LISTCOLUMNID));


CREATE TABLE PROJECT_RECORDS (
RECORDS_ROWID number(3) not null,
RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID number (3) not null references PROJECT_TABLES(PROJECT_LISTCOLUMNID)on delete cascade,
RECORDS_LISTID number (3) not null,
RECORDS_RECORDVALUE varchar2 (25),
primary key(RECORDS_ROWID, RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID));

commit;
```

The reasoning for adding multiple primary keys to the PROJECT_TABLES table is that the listcolumnid isn't unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `listcolumnid` is not unique, you cannot put a foreign key constraint on it. A foreign key always refrences exatcly one parent row. So you probably should use both columns in your foreign key (assuming there is really a 1:n relation):

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT_RECORDS (
RECORDS_ROWID number(3) not null,
RECORDS_ID number(3) not null,
RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID number (3) not null,
RECORDS_LISTID number (3) not null,
RECORDS_RECORDVALUE varchar2 (25),
primary key(RECORDS_ROWID, RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID),
foreign key fk_project_projectrecords (RECORDS_ID, RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID) references PROJECT_TABLES(PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_LISTCOLUMNID)on delete cascade,
);
```

(The example is using your prefix naming convention, I would change `RECORDS_ID` to `PROJECT_ID`, same for `RECORDS_LISTCOLUMNID`)

Comment: Yes, I fixed that (as I see, you to)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your syntax.  You don't do this:

```
, fieldname datatype references (something)
```

You do this:

```
, primary key(somefield)
, foreign key (somefield) references sometable(somefield)
```